# PHP - Returning an SQL table with foreach statement, only returning the value of the first column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, wamp

I'm trying to display an SQL table using PHP, by only passing in the table name and then working out the number of rows and columns to display the table correctly.

So far I've managed to retrieve the column names, but I'm having trouble getting it to display more than the first column's value, like this:

```
ID | lastName | firstname | etc..
10 | 11 | 13 | 16 | 19 | etc..
```

As an example.

Here is my code for retrieving the column headers:

```
    $STH = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
    $STH->execute(); 

    $STH = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $headerQuery = $conn->prepare("DESCRIBE employees");
    $headerQuery->execute();
    $table_fields = $headerQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    $num_fields = count($table_fields);

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>";

    for ($x=0;$x<$num_fields;$x++)
        {
            echo "<th>$table_fields[$x]</th>";
        }

    echo "</tr>";
```

And here is the code for retrieving the values, which is not working correctly:

```
for ($x=0;$x<$num_fields;$x++)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($table_fields as &$fieldname) 
                {
                    while($row = $STH->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<td>" . $row[$fieldname] . "</td>";
                        }
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Any assistance is extremely appreciated, along with any advice on how I could do what I've already got working more efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the query in $STH

Comment: Oops, sorry - I missed that out, added it to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like such an idiot for missing it, I was using the complete wrong variable for counting the rows (and not to mention the loop structure was all wrong, too)

```
    $fieldValue = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $tableName"); 
    $fieldValue->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // We'll come back to this later.

    $headerQuery = $conn->prepare("DESCRIBE $tableName"); // Get our table headers from the input table.
    $headerQuery->execute();
    $table_fields = $headerQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    $num_fields = count($table_fields); // Find out how many headers there actually are and make it a useful variable.

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowscount FROM $tableName"; // Run a count query to find out how many rows are in the table.
    $results = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // n.b. - This comes out as a multi-dimensional array. This is annoying.
    $num_rows = $results[0]['rowscount']; // Get the value out of the array so it's not clogging up the code.

    // echo ("Number of rows: " . $num_rows); // Debugging - this was showing as 0 or 1 for the longest time, until I realised it was multidimensional above.

    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";  // Build the table

    for ($x=0;$x<$num_fields;$x++) // Working through the headers one by one.
        {
            echo "<th>$table_fields[$x]</th>"; // This was the easy bit, displaying the column headers.
        }

    echo "</tr>"; 

    for($x=0;$x<$num_rows;$x++) // Now we need to go down the rows, 
        {
            while($row = $fieldValue->fetch()) // This is where our $fieldValue comes in, pluck out the value of each field before putting it in.
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach ($table_fields as &$fieldname) 
                    {
                        echo "<td>" . $row[$fieldname] . "</td>"; 
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }           
        }   
    $conn = null; // Terminate the connection. You're not needed anymore.
    echo "</table>";   //Close the table
```